Training Result and GPU Memory issues when training Faster RCNN model from PyTorch library
Approach
I attempted to train the pretrained fasterrcnn_resnet50_fpn_v2 model from the PyTorch library on a custom dataset. Once I got the output I was unsure what to make of it as the mAP score seems really low (around 0.1).
Issue #1: Don't understand the results
Can someone please take a look at my graph and tell me how it is? I thought mAP score (calculated by downloading mean_ap file from torchmetrics github cause I couldn't get it to work) could go close to 1 but mine seems to have peaked at around 0.01.

Issue #2 - GPU Memory Usage
When I first ran the code, if I interrupted the code GPU Memory would still be used until I restarted the computer. ChatGPT suggested I add a function call to fix this and I did. Below is the function used:
import sys
import signal
def cleanup(signum, frame):
    """Catching interrupts and cleaning up cache"""
    print("\n\n\t<Interrupt Received. Cleaning Up...>")
    
    torch.cuda.empty_cache()
    sys.exit(0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    """First Fn. to be called when program is run"""
    
    # Call function to clear cache when interrupted
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, cleanup)   # By Ctrl + C
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTSTP, cleanup)  # By Ctrl + Z
    
    # Rest of the code here...

This feels to me like a stopgap measure and I'm not sure what the coding best practice is that I'm actually missing (since I've run other peoples code and never come across this piece of code and it always seems to works fine for them).
Attached below are my training code and model per epoch code:
def main(directory, num_epochs, batch_size=4, pretrain=True, learning_rate = 0.005, momentum = 0.9, weight_decay=0.005, data_split={"train":0.6, "test":0.2, "val":0.2}, save_after=10, device='cuda'):
    """Main Training Loop"""
    
    # [Create necessary folders]
    output_folder_name = f"Ep-{num_epochs}_BS-{batch_size}_Pre-{pretrain}_LR-{learning_rate}_Mo-{momentum}_WD-{weight_decay}_Day-{datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S')}"
    os.makedirs(output_folder_name, exist_ok=True)
    os.makedirs(os.path.join(output_folder_name, "chkpts"), exist_ok=True)
    os.makedirs(os.path.join(output_folder_name, "preds"), exist_ok=True)
    
    # Get number of classes based on subfolders in directory
    num_classes = len([entry for entry in os.listdir(directory) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(directory, entry))])
    
    # [Get Dataset Split from Custom Dataset]
    transform_to_tensor = torchvision.transforms.Compose([torchvision.transforms.ToTensor()])
    train_dataset = CustomDataset(directory, transforms=transform_to_tensor, split='train', dataset_split=data_split)
    test_dataset = CustomDataset(directory, transforms=transform_to_tensor, split='test', dataset_split=data_split)
    val_dataset = CustomDataset(directory, transforms=transform_to_tensor, split='val', dataset_split=data_split)

    # [Define DataLoaders]
    train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True, collate_fn=collate_fn)
    test_loader = DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False, collate_fn=collate_fn)
    val_loader = DataLoader(val_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False, collate_fn=collate_fn)
    print("<Dataset and DataLoaders defined>")

    # [Load fasterrcnn_resnet50_fpn_v2 from PyTorch library]
    model = torchvision.models.detection.fasterrcnn_resnet50_fpn_v2(pretrained=pretrain)
    in_features = model.roi_heads.box_predictor.cls_score.in_features
    model.roi_heads.box_predictor = torchvision.models.detection.faster_rcnn.FastRCNNPredictor(in_features, num_classes + 1)  # Adjust for number of classes
    print("<Faster RCNN ResNet50 FPN v2 Model Loaded from PyTorch Library>")

    # [Define Optimiser and GradScaler for using mixed precision]
    optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate, momentum=momentum, weight_decay=weight_decay)
    scaler = GradScaler()
    
    # Create descriptions for different losses
    loss_desc = {"loss_classifier":"Classification Loss (Fast RCNN)", "loss_box_reg":"Box Regression Loss (Fast RCNN)", "loss_objectness":"Objectness Loss (RPN)", "loss_rpn_box_reg":" Box Regression Loss (RPN)", "total":"Total Loss"}
    
    # [Initialise dictionary with lists to store different losses]
    test_losses = {key : [] for key in loss_desc.keys()}
    train_losses = {key : [] for key in loss_desc.keys()}
    
    model_mAP_change = []
    classes_mAP_change = [[] for _ in range(num_classes)]

    # [Training the model on the dataset]
    try:
        for epoch in range(1, num_epochs + 1):
            print(f"\n\t\t\tEpoch: [{epoch}/{num_epochs}]")
            train_loss_epoch = train_model(model, device, train_loader, optimizer, epoch, scaler)
            test_loss_epoch = test_model(model, device, test_loader, epoch)
            full_mAP_epoch = validate_model(model, device, val_loader, output_folder_name, epoch, num_classes)  # Validation step with mAP

            # Append losses and model_mAP to respective lists
            for loss_name in loss_desc.keys():
                test_losses[loss_name].append(test_loss_epoch[loss_name])
                train_losses[loss_name].append(train_loss_epoch[loss_name])

            model_mAP_change.append(full_mAP_epoch['map'])
            for cNum, class_mAP_value in enumerate(full_mAP_epoch['map_per_class']):
                classes_mAP_change[cNum].append(class_mAP_value)
            
            save_to_csv(os.path.join(output_folder_name, "training_stats.csv"), epoch, train_loss_epoch, test_loss_epoch, full_mAP_epoch, loss_desc)
            if epoch % save_after == 0 or epoch == num_epochs:
                save_checkpoint(model, optimizer, epoch, os.path.join(output_folder_name, "chkpts", f"epoch_{epoch}.pth"))
                
            del train_loss_epoch, test_loss_epoch, full_mAP_epoch
            torch.cuda.empty_cache()
            gc.collect()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("\n\n\t<Interrupt Received. Cleaning Up...>")
        
        torch.cuda.empty_cache()
        sys.exit(0)
        

    # Create a plot of the losses and metrics
    create_graph(
        train_losses = train_losses,
        test_losses = test_losses,
        model_mAPs = model_mAP_change,
        classes_mAPs = classes_mAP_change,
        epoch_num = num_epochs,
        loss_dict = loss_desc,
        store_location = os.path.join(output_folder_name, "metrics_plotted.png"),
        graph_title = f"Faster RCNN ResNET FPN v2\nEp-{num_epochs}_BS-{batch_size}_Pre-{pretrain}_LR-{learning_rate}_Mo-{momentum}_WD-{weight_decay}"
    )
    
    del model, optimizer, scaler
    del train_losses, test_losses, model_mAP_change, classes_mAP_change
    del train_dataset, train_loader, test_dataset, test_loader, val_dataset, val_loader
    torch.cuda.empty_cache()
    gc.collect()


def train_model(model, device, loader, optimizer, epoch, scaler):
    """Training Function with GradScaler for mixed precision"""
    
    model.to(device)
    model.train()
    dict_aggregate = {'loss_classifier':0, 'loss_box_reg':0, 'loss_objectness':0, 'loss_rpn_box_reg':0, 'total':0}
    epoch_start_time = time.time()
    
    # Running through batches in dataset loader
    for batch_idx, (images, targets, image_paths) in tqdm(enumerate(loader), desc=f"Training Epoch {epoch}", unit="batch", total=len(loader)):
        images = [image.to(device) for image in images]
        targets = [{k: v.to(device) for k, v in t.items()} for t in targets]

        optimizer.zero_grad()
        with autocast():  # Mixed precision for training
            loss_dict = model(images, targets)
            losses = sum(loss for loss in loss_dict.values())
        scaler.scale(losses).backward()  # Scale loss for mixed-precision training
        scaler.step(optimizer)           # Step with scaled optimizer
        scaler.update()                  # Update scaler
            
        # Store loss for batch
        for key, value in loss_dict.items():
            dict_aggregate[key] += value.item()
        dict_aggregate['total'] += losses.item()
        
        del images, targets, loss_dict, losses
        torch.cuda.empty_cache()
        gc.collect()
        

    for key in dict_aggregate.keys():
        dict_aggregate[key] /= len(loader)
    print(f"\t\tTrain Epoch: {epoch}\tAverage Loss: {dict_aggregate['total']:.6f}\tTime: {(time.time() - epoch_start_time):.4f}s\n")
    return dict_aggregate

Issue #3: Poorly written code
How can I write code that is memory efficient and where can I learn best practice when writing ML/DL code?
Below, I have attached a link to a GitHub repo with all the code and output files for this particular endeavor:
[Link to the GitHub Repo with code for training Faster RCNN]
My code seems like a Frankenstein monster to me as I would run head first into issues, look up solutions for them online or using ChatGPT, modify code to correct that particular issue and carry on. This seems to me like it would make me develop poor coding habits and as if I am missing out on coding best practices.
I would be grateful for any and all advice.
Issue #1: Don't understand the results
I tried to look up what mAP scores I could find for Faster RCNN and the paper says they got upwards of 69 as the score and graphs I found online seem to display similar trends. Am I training for too few epochs or is it an issue with my code?
Issue #2: GPU Memory Usage
I tried using torch.cuda.empty_cache() and gc.collect() wherever I could but those didn't work when I interrupted the code mid execution. This is when I tried the code mentioned previously and it worked. However, I don't understand why the issue came about in the first place.
Issue #3: Poorly written code
My code feels to me at least to be following no best practices and overall poorly written. I tried adding comments but that all just seems like trying to fix a broken vase using duct tape.

Posts need to have one question, not three.
